# Tutorial / guide to copying and pasting utf-8 text to and from OSX PasteBoard / Clipboard

Tags: objective-c, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm currently adding clipboard support to my gui API. It inputs and outputs in UTF-8 as std string.

I now need to add OSX support but I have almost no experience with Objective-C. Is there some sort of tutorial that might show interaction with std::string, converting from utf-8 to whatever osx natively uses, then copying it to the clipboard and vice versa?

Thanks

I just want to be able to take a utf-8 encoded std string and copy it to osx clipboard and to be able to copy some text from something like textedit and paste it into my application as a UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string class is NSString in Cocoa

`NSString initWithUTF8String` to create a cocoa string from UTF-8 char*

`NSString UTF8String` for vice versa

For simple pasting

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CopyAndPaste

```
NSString *string = @"String to be copied";
NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteBoard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSStringPboardType, nil] owner:nil];
[pasteBoard setString:string forType:NSStringPboardType];
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to get the string in the pasteboard as well?